# Why does it type check?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typechecking, fp-ts

This one doesn't make sense to me:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import * as TE from 'fp-ts/lib/TaskEither'

export const getIntent = (sessionId: string, input: string) => process.env.INTENT_URL
  ? TE.tryCatch(
      () => axios.post(`${process.env.INTENT_URL}`,{sessionId, input}),
      reason => String(reason))
  : TE.left(Error("No INTENT_URL")
)
```

The `Left` is `String` and/or `Error` which is obviously not equal. How come this type checks???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same reason why this typechecks:

```js
export const getIntent = () => process.env.INTENT_URL
  ? true
  : "false"
```

You don't have a return type annotation on your function, so typescript automatically widens the return type to union type to cover the return values.

Comment: Don’t you think this feels wrong? I never said I want to widen the return type.

Comment: Dunno. I admit, it looks kinda strange, but in practice I personally never had any issues with that. Usually its a good habit to always have full type annotations on top-level functions. There is even a eslint rule to enforce it.

Comment: Maybe one of the strict compiler options disables such behaviour? Not sure.

Comment: If I want a sum type, I specify `Either` explicitly. If I want a product type, I specify `Tuple` explicitly.

Comment: On top level you should specify the types so it's not a problem. But you might write lambda functions and don't specify the types. The example you give a simple. In practice you will have variables and may write it wrong and you don't notice it!

Comment: As I said, in practice I have a return type annotation

Comment: You shouldn't use complex functions for lambdas. And for simple ones its not a problem.

Comment: Anyway, I am not in any relation to typescript team, so discussing whether its right or wrong behaviour is kinda pointless :) That's just how it it.

Comment: Not a complex one. Just one return different variables and hard to notice.

Comment: You still gonna get an error eventually. Just a bit later in the code.

Comment: If its a lambda and you pass it as an argument to another higher-order function, then it will fail typechecking there - it won't fit there.